# Unable to establish connection between Impala and Rstudio using rimpala.connect()

Tags: r, rhadoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am unable to establish connection between Impala and RStudio.

I am using Cloudera quickstart vm for Cloudera Manager and RStudio

Please see code below and advise if anything could be done:

#### Initialization

```
library(RImpala)
rimpala.init(libs="/home/cloudera/Documents/impala-jdbc-0.5-2")
```

#### Output

```
[1] "Classpath added successfully"
```

#### Connecting

```
 rimpala.connect("127.0.0.1","21050")
```

#### Output

```
Error: null

[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Are you sure Impala actually running?

Comment: Yes Impala is running. I ran the code after restarting all the Cloudera quickstart services with good health.